# /etc/xdg is missing files

Tags: 14.04, autostart

Most of my settings in /etc/xdg have disappeared somehow for no apparent reason. I am running 14.04

I first noticed a problem with system setting not working properly. See:
[Systems Settings is completely empty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529368/systems-settings-is-completely-empty)

Solved by getting hold of a fresh copy of /etc/xdg/menus/unitycc.menu

Then I noticed that my wifi icon was missing from the top right hand corner.

Solved by getting hold of a fresh copy of /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop

Then I realised that software centre was failing with an authentication error when I tried to install stuff.

Solved by getting hold of a fresh copy of /etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent1.desktop

These files do not seem to reinstate themselves even if I do a

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall <package name>
```

for the package that they originate from (I don't know why). I have to find the right package, manually unpack it, find the relevant file, and copy it into the right location.

My question:

Is there a better way to fix this? If so what?

Am I missing anything else from these directories?

Current contents of /etc/xdg:

```
matt@matt-laptop:/etc/xdg/autostart$ cd /etc/xdg
matt@matt-laptop:/etc/xdg$ ls
autostart  menus
matt@matt-laptop:/etc/xdg$ ls autostart
gnome-settings-daemon.desktop  nm-applet.desktop
gnome-sound-applet.desktop     polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop
matt@matt-laptop:/etc/xdg$ ls menus
gnomecc.menu  unitycc.menu
```

Comment: Try running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure  xdg-utils` . If that doesn't help, try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xdg-utils`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I restore configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files)

Answer (score 0):

You may need first to purge the package:

```
sudo apt-get purge <package name>
```

then install it:

```
sudo apt-get install <package name>
```

with this, the package's conffile under */etc/xdg/autostart/* will be installed as you want.

Comment: I doubt purging package and installing it will do anything, because OP already said they tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall <package name>`. Worth trying , but I doubt this will help. Nonetheless, good attempt !